# npm creates huge number of files, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, npm, phpstorm

The way I read [this section of the PhpStorm manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/installing-and-removing-external-software-using-node-package-manager.html#d117268e540), to add a development tool I can do this:

> If a tool is a documentation or a test framework, which are of no need
>   for those who are going to re-use your application, it is helpful to
>   have it excluded from download for the future. This is done by marking
>   the tool as a development dependency, which actually means adding the
>   tool in the devDependencies section of the package.json file.
>
> With PhpStorm, you can have a tool marked as a development dependency
>   right during installation. Do one of the following:
>
> Switch to the project root folder and type the following command at
>   the command line prompt: `npm install --dev  <tool name>`
>
> [...]

It seems this is not correct or I understood it wrong, because when I ran

`npm install --dev del`

to get a tool that can delete files to clear the cache during development, npm created a deeply nested folder structure several gigabytes in size with millions of files. I killed it and then spent half an hour moving the deeper folders further up in the tree so that the paths were short enough for Windows to delete them.

What did I do wrong?

By the way, adding it to package.json -> devDependencies and running `npm install` works fine.

node 0.12.0, npm 2.5.1

Comment: Well, instead of wiping it you could have inspected what packages cause this folder to be that bloated. It's often several packages out of the entire list that contain most of the weight.

Comment: I did have a look, but it wasn't that way. The same packages were installed over and over again, nested deeper and deeper. You can probably easily reproduce it locally, just run `npm install --dev del`.

Comment: Well, so far I'm getting a boatload of `npm ERR! unpack Could not read data for <package>@<version>` and a bunch of version comlpaints. I may be running a too different version of `node`, provide yours in the question please. `npm` as well.

Comment: Well, even given that terrible situation and a different OS (Linux Mint, Ubuntu flavor) this reproduces nicely. If a gigabyte-sized bloat can be considered "nice"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known bug, https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5554. This flag will be removed soon - see https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6200. I'd suggest using `npm install --save-dev` instead - but you need creating a package.json first. In PHPStorm this can be done using `File | New | package.json`